# Wrong year pd.to_datetime

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with dates stored like objects in the format of
`2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00`

I want to extract year as a new column:

`tp['year'] = pd.to_datetime(tp.datefield).dt.year, utc=True)`

(without `utc=True` i get: ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True)

But for dates like `2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00` I get year 2019 when it should be 2020. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong, if convert to `utc` get:

```
tp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tp.datefield, utc=True)
print (tp)
                   datefield                      date
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00 2019-12-31 23:00:00+00:00
```

So year is `2019`.

Btw, for me working it correct, pandas 1.1.1:

```
tp['year'] = pd.to_datetime(tp.datefield).dt.year
print (tp)

                   datefield  year
0  2020-01-01 00:00:00+01:00  2020
```

Comment: Ok, but I want it to be 2020. That is how the data appear in the application reading the SQL data from. Maybe I can add an hour.

Comment: @BERA - What is your pandas version? Also If not working `tp['year'] = pd.to_datetime(tp.datefield).dt.year` is possible test `tp['year'] = pd.to_datetime(tp.datefield.astype(str)).dt.year` ?

Comment: version pandas: 0.24.2

Comment: @BERA - Hoe working solution from comment above? If not, is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: I must be misunderstanding my data. Now all `datefield` records are already datetime... A simple `df['year'] = df.datefield.apply(lambda x: x.year)` gives correct year

Comment: @BERA - Or `tp['year'] = tp.datefield.dt.year`